# How to efficiently compute $\sum_{k} \prod_{i=1}^N \binom{N-k_i}{k_i} \frac{N}{N-k_i}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I want to evaluate the sum
$$
    \sum_{k} \prod_{i=1}^N \binom{N-k_i}{k_i} \frac{N}{N-k_i}
$$
where the sum ranges over all ordered partitions $(k_1, \dots, k_N)$ such that $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^N k_i = K$ and $0 \le k_i < N$ for all $i$.

My attempt:
My original term was something like $\binom{N-k_i}{k_i}+\binom{N-k_i-1}{k_i-1}$.
I simplified to one hoping it may help.
N is constant and so my thoughts are in direction if we can express it as some coefficient in expansion of something like $[1+f(x)]^N$

As @greg-martin pointed out, it's better to work out special cases first,

For $K=1$, we get $N^2$,

For $K=2$, we get $N^2(N^2-3)/2$,

For $K=N$, we get $\binom{N^2 - N - 1}{N - 1} + N (-1)^N$ ([A197990](https://oeis.org/A197990))

For $K= N\lfloor{N/2}\rfloor$, we get $N^N$ ([A085529](https://oeis.org/A085529)) when K is odd,                  or $2^N$ when K is even

For $K> N\lfloor{N/2}\rfloor$, we always get $0$

Comment: Your sum and product don't appear to indicate which variable(s) are changing over which range.

Comment: @MishaLavrov The product expression is for one particular partition of K ie {$k_1,k_2,k_3...k_n$} and then you sum for all possible ordered partitions.

Comment: Okay, I have edited so that your notation actually says this. It is not 100% clear to me if $k_1, \dots, k_n$ is an ordered or unordered partition; you should clarify.

Comment: @MishaLavrov ordered

Answer (score 3):

Numerical calculation of the cases up to $N=8$ suggest that the quantity you describe is [sequence A197990 in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/A197990); that link has more information about various equivalent descriptions of that sequence. In particular, Harvey P. Dale reports there that a closed form is $N\binom{N^2 - N - 1}{N - 1} + N (-1)^N$.

(General practical advice: when dealing with an integer sequence, always compute several terms and see what OEIS has to say about it!)

Comment: How is it independent of K? You mean you substituted K=N ?

Comment: to clarify the question K has upto N partitions which sum to K ie $k_1+k_2+k_3+..+k_N=K$ , sum of the partitions = N will be a special case of that. Anyways it has been a very good help in the right direction. I don't know why I didn't think of searching special cases in oeis. Let me see if I can find similar expression for K=N-1 or K=N+1, and may be try to generalise from there. K=1 gives me $N^2$ .

Comment: ah true, didn't notice there were two different parameters